# How to use output_logs in ansible docker_container module

Tags: docker, ansible

Here's a role I'm running:

```
- name: run hello-world
  docker_container:
    detach: no
    output_logs: yes
    name: test
    image: hello-world
    log_driver: json-file
```

and here's the command I'm running:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml -i=<some_remote_host>,
```

and output:

```
BECOME password: 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<some_host>]

TASK [test : run hello-world] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [<some_host>]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
<some_host>              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What am I missing? How do I print logs without registering output and printing it in a dedicated node (which I now works, but seems artificial, if we have a dedicated option for this)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer or a workaround for this?